# Where does JPSoft's Take Command store the (per user) config INI files?

Tags: windows-xp

I use Take Command from JPSoft extensively.

Lately my work computer's Windows refused to boot so I took the opportunity to do a clean setup.

I now need to find the Take Command configuration files (especcialy for my command buttons) so that I can copy them from my backup to the new installation. Where might I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it ... Take Command stores the INI file in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<nt account>\Local Settings\Application Data\JPSoft
```

which is a bit unexpected since our IT departement sets up the machines to store 'Documents and Settings' on the Z:\ (aka 'Data') drive...

Answer (score 1):

For readers in the future, I recommend using a tool like Disk Pulse or SysInternal's Process Monitor. If you have either of those running, and you were to modify Take Command's settings, you would have been able to see which file was modified (or registry entry if using ProcMon).

Disk Pulse is more user friendly, while Process Monitor has more options and allows monitoring changes to Registry and Network activity, etc.

Comment: Good tip, thanks. Do you have a pointer to a 'how-to' write-up that shows the technique you describe?

Comment: Not exactly, but it is pretty simple. After you install one of those programs, run the program. It will catch all disk changes at first. First, you'll need to filter out junk. Both programs allow you to right click on items to quickly filter out "spam". Process Monitor also tracks Registry and Network activity, etc, so click off Network Activity at least since that isn't related (config settings could be in the registry though). After you enable the program and filter, make a simple change in the Take Command options screen, and you should be able to see the file name pretty easily.